# Signature error using AWS SNS/SMS to send SMS message using Civi extension - uk.compucorp.civicrm.amazonsns

Tags: sms, aws

AWS Error - Error Sending SMS through Amazon SNS [SignatureDoesNotMatch]: - The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.

Using amazonsns extension.    Can send individual messages using AWS console but errors when sending individual or mass sms from Civi.    AWS user has full permissions for SNS.    AWS mentions Version 4 generates signing key derived from signing access key rather than secret access key itself.

Any suggestions for troubleshooting this issue?   Is extension generating the signing key using V4?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.   AWS has an option for a user to have either console usage or programmatic or both.

need to set programmatic use  when creating the user and permissions for SNS as needed.  Full SNS access permissions seem to work fine.